# Equivalent command line call for airplane mode

Tags: linux, wifi, bluetooth

Can someone suggest how to turn on airplane mode from command line instead of using the GUI? Also can someone list what all are turned off by enabling airplane mode or how to turn off all radios including bluetooth and wifi?

Is there a difference between hardware shutdown and device driver shutdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone suggest how to turn on airplane mode from command line
>   instead of using the GUI?

```
nmcli networking off
```

> Also can someone list what all are turned off by enabling airplane
>   mode or how to turn off all radios including bluetooth and wifi?

You can see all the radios states (including bluetooth and wifi) using `nmcli general`. Then you can select between radio states using `nmcli radio`.

> Is there a difference between hardware shutdown and device driver
>   shutdown?

This paradox implies the well known debate of *which is better, a software initiated shutdown/soft-reboot or a hardware shutdown/hard-reboot?*. You will easily find dozens of websites out there answering this better but let's mention here these three points at least:

`A) Security:` The driver shutdown sends an ACPI instruction. If something blocks this instruction and hide the state of the device, you may continue running it. Less security. The hardware shutdown produces directly on the hardware. More security.

`B) Integrity:` The driver shutdown instruction process depends on the rest of the software environment, so it could be modified, fall on loops, be frozen, or even terminated, without the signal arrival. A hardware shutdown instruction directly sent on-hardware to the device generally make the process more certain and bugs-resistant.

`C) Automatization:` It is easy and cheaper to implement automate shutdowns using software methods rather than hardware ones. You can implement software too on the logic that starts a hardware shutdown but, by its own nature, normally requires human (or at least bot) intervention.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following commands:

Enter in airplane mode

```
sudo rfkill block all
```

Exit from airplane mode

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

List the status of all available wireless devices

```
sudo rfkill list
```

Comment: It works without `sudo` on my machine